# How to implement plugin architecture into Asp.Net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, plugins

I'm trying to accomplish something like Blogengine.Net's way of handlling extensions/plugins. The goal is to have a plugin as a ordinary class file (not a dll), put it in a folder and the webapplication should load it dynamically.

Any help, links, anything is much appreciated.

Don't really know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you go get the source code and read it to figure out how it works in BlogEngine.Net. That is really the best and fastest way to accomplish what you want.  Frankly, it's what I like best about open source.  You can download the latest source from http://blogengine.codeplex.com/releases/view/39387.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already downloaded the source code. But I think that I still need to have some more information about the theory about it. And one more problem is that Blogengine.net is using a website and App_Code-folder to accomplish their solution. I was hoping for information about the "same" solution but in a web application.